# How to pass json query object from client to server for Meteor collection find

Tags: angularjs, json, mongodb, meteor

I have a complex query that depends on user inputs from client, then I form a json object to query the collection, and invoke the Meteor.subscribe again with the updated query.

For example as in the following mongo db collection:

```
{ _id: 1, results: [ { product: "abc", manufacturer: "mfg 1" }, { product: "xyz", manufacturer: "mfg 2" } ] }
{ _id: 2, results: [ { product: "abc", manufacturer: "mfg 3" }, { product: "xyz", manufacturer: "mfg 4" } ] }
{ _id: 3, results: [ { product: "abc", manufacturer: "mfg 5" }, { product: "xyz", manufacturer: "mfg 6" } ] }
```

user enter product: "xyz", and manufacturer: "mfg 2", I create a query JSON object like the following:

```
scope.searchTerms = {};
scope.searchTerms.results = {};
var match = {};

match.product = "xyz";
match.manufacturer = "mfg 2";

searchTerms.results.$elemMatch = match;

Meteor.subscribe("products", scope.searchTerms));
```

Then, I have two problems:

1. Server always return the full set of records;
2. The searchTerms always contain **proto**.

I copied the content of searchTerms, and then hard code for the server to publish, and it works perfectly fine.

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
Meteor.publish('products', function (selector) {
    return Products.find(selector);
});
```

Please help.

Comment: You are assigning `match` to `searchTerms` and send `scope.searchTerms`. Could that be it? In addition, I would send just the 2 strings and construct the query on the server (makes it easier to validate).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of the same, however, the actual collection has many sub arrays like that, it would be huge headache to pass strings to server and construct the json object from there, and it would be much easier to let client side build the query and simply pass on to the meteor collection publish, and then let mongodb handle the rest.

Comment: OK then. For starters, make sure that the server gets the selector correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I have finally found the problem.

For the match object to pass onto mongo, we cannot simply assign the values like the following:

```
var match = {};

match.product = "xyz";
match.manufacturer = "mfg 2";
```

We have to do a different way:

```
var match = {};

match['product'] = "xyz";
match['manufacturer'] = "mfg 2";
```

It is really weird.